# How to restrict attributes of child elements based on parent attribute or position in XSD schema

Tags: xml, xsd, xslt-1.0

Trying to design a XSD Schema for this sample XML. From external API so can't change it. Problem I run into is how to restrict the attributes on the rows.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<eveapi version="2">
  <currentTime>2014-04-21 06:07:26</currentTime>
  <result>
    <characterID>123</characterID>
    <name>Me</name>
    <rowset name="skills" key="typeID" columns="typeID,skillpoints,level,published">
      <row typeID="3424" skillpoints="16000" level="3" published="1" />
      <row typeID="3318" skillpoints="2829" level="2" published="1" />
      <row typeID="3425" skillpoints="2829" level="2" published="1" />
      <row typeID="3451" skillpoints="500" level="1" published="1" />
    </rowset>
    <rowset name="certificates" key="certificateID" columns="certificateID">
        <row certificateID="1"/>
    </rowset>
    <rowset name="corporationRoles" key="roleID" columns="roleID,roleName">
      <row roleID="1" roleName="roleDirector" />
    </rowset>
    <rowset name="corporationRolesAtHQ" key="roleID" columns="roleID,roleName">
      <row roleID="1" roleName="roleDirector" />
    </rowset>
    <rowset name="corporationRolesAtBase" key="roleID" columns="roleID,roleName">
      <row roleID="1" roleName="roleDirector" />
    </rowset>
    <rowset name="corporationRolesAtOther" key="roleID" columns="roleID,roleName">
      <row roleID="1" roleName="roleDirector" />
    </rowset>
    <rowset name="corporationTitles" key="titleID" columns="titleID,titleName">
      <row titleID="1" titleName="Member" />
      <row titleID="2" titleName="Member Senior" />
      <row titleID="8192" titleName="Research Director" />
    </rowset>
  </result>
  <cachedUntil>2014-04-21 12:04:26</cachedUntil>
</eveapi>
```

And I've got this from my IDE generating based on the sample.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="eveapi" type="eveapiType"/>
  <xs:complexType name="rowType">
    <xs:simpleContent>
      <xs:extension base="xs:string">
        <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="typeID" use="optional"/>
        <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="skillpoints" use="optional"/>
        <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="level" use="optional"/>
        <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="published" use="optional"/>
        <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="certificateID" use="optional"/>
        <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="roleID" use="optional"/>
        <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="roleName" use="optional"/>
        <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="titleID" use="optional"/>
        <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="titleName" use="optional"/>
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:simpleContent>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="rowsetType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element type="rowType" name="row" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="name" use="optional"/>
    <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="key" use="optional"/>
    <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="columns" use="optional"/>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="eveapiType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element type="xs:string" name="currentTime"/>
      <xs:element type="resultType" name="result"/>
      <xs:element type="xs:string" name="cachedUntil"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="version"/>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="resultType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element type="xs:string" name="characterID"/>
      <xs:element type="xs:string" name="name"/>
      <xs:element type="rowsetType" name="rowset" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

But it just merges the attributes so `<row>` allows any or all of the attributes no matter the `<rowset>`.

Any help would be great as I've tried everything I could think of and most give errors in XSD validators about using abstract wrong or being indeterminate somewhere.

I'm still interested in a XSD only solution but just in case someone else has similar problem and find this I'll relate a two step solution using XSL style sheet/transform and XSD.

### # Two Step Solution #

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml"
        version="1.0"
        encoding="utf-8"
        omit-xml-declaration="no"
        standalone="no"
        indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="rowset">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="@name">
                <xsl:element name="{@name}">
                    <xsl:copy-of select="@key"/>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="@columns"/>
                    <xsl:apply-templates/>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The result ends up looking something like this:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<eveapi version="2">
  <currentTime>2014-04-21 06:07:26</currentTime>
  <result>
    <characterID>123</characterID>
    <name>Me</name>
    <skills key="typeID" columns="typeID,skillpoints,level,published">
      <row typeID="3424" skillpoints="16000" level="3" published="1" />
      <row typeID="3318" skillpoints="2829" level="2" published="1" />
      <row typeID="3425" skillpoints="2829" level="2" published="1" />
      <row typeID="3451" skillpoints="500" level="1" published="1" />
    </skills>
    <certificates key="certificateID" columns="certificateID">
        <row certificateID="1"/>
    </certificates>
    <corporationRoles key="roleID" columns="roleID,roleName">
      <row roleID="1" roleName="roleDirector" />
    </corporationRoles>
    <corporationRolesAtHQ key="roleID" columns="roleID,roleName">
      <row roleID="1" roleName="roleDirector" />
    </corporationRolesAtHQ>
    <corporationRolesAtBase key="roleID" columns="roleID,roleName">
      <row roleID="1" roleName="roleDirector" />
    </corporationRolesAtBase>
    <corporationRolesAtOther key="roleID" columns="roleID,roleName">
      <row roleID="1" roleName="roleDirector" />
    </corporationRolesAtOther>
    <corporationTitles key="titleID" columns="titleID,titleName">
      <row titleID="1" titleName="Member" />
      <row titleID="2" titleName="Member Senior" />
      <row titleID="8192" titleName="Research Director" />
    </corporationTitles>
  </result>
  <cachedUntil>2014-04-21 12:04:26</cachedUntil>
</eveapi>
```

To just give quick explanation what it does is replace any `rowset` element that have `name` attribute with element equal to attribute value and copies the remaining attributes over to the new element. It'll work with recursive `rowset`s which I needed and some may not include names on sub-elements so need to handle that as well by just using a regular element copy in that case. The rest is simple standard tree copy. Now that the XML is transform the XSD is easy to make and in my case my IDE can even make them for me ;-)

Comment: It's not trivial because your rowsets are actually different types, despite having the same name. Using the `xs:assert` element from XSD 1.1 you can use XPath to restrict the contents and attributes based on  the presence of certain attributes and elements.

Comment: You're correct that they really are different types. I'd still like an XSD solution if someone can come up with one but think I go with a xslt transform step before validating. The problem just goes away then. I'll see about updating question to show that solution.

Answer (score 0):

The transformation makes it much easier, and since you now have different types you can solve the problem with XSD 1.0.

You can generate a XSD, but it's useful to at lease edit it by hand later so you can decide what the actual rules are for all your file, since that generation can generate XSD that may be too generic or too specific (since it's only using one file as source).

This is an edited XSD that will validate the second XML that you posted:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <xs:element name="eveapi" type="eveapiType"/>
    <xs:complexType name="eveapiType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element type="xs:string" name="currentTime"/>
            <xs:element type="ResultType" name="result"/>
            <xs:element type="xs:string" name="cachedUntil"/>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="version"/>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="ResultType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element type="xs:string" name="characterID"/>
            <xs:element type="xs:string" name="name"/>
            <xs:element type="SkillsType" name="skills"/>
            <xs:element type="CertificatesType" name="certificates"/>
            <xs:element type="CorporationRolesType" name="corporationRoles"/>
            <xs:element type="CorporationRolesType" name="corporationRolesAtHQ"/>
            <xs:element type="CorporationRolesType" name="corporationRolesAtBase"/>
            <xs:element type="CorporationRolesType" name="corporationRolesAtOther"/>
            <xs:element type="CorporationTitlesType" name="corporationTitles"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="RowSetType">
        <xs:attribute name="key" type="xs:NMTOKEN"/>
        <xs:attribute name="columns" type="xs:string" />
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="SkillsType">
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:extension base="RowSetType">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="row" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                        <xs:complexType>
                            <xs:attribute name="typeID" type="xs:string"/>
                            <xs:attribute name="skillpoints" type="xs:integer"/>
                            <xs:attribute name="level" type="xs:integer"/>
                            <xs:attribute name="published" type="xs:integer"/>
                        </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="CertificatesType">
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:extension base="RowSetType">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="row" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                        <xs:complexType>
                            <xs:attribute name="certificateID" type="xs:string"/>
                        </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="CorporationRolesType">
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:extension base="RowSetType">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="row" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                        <xs:complexType>
                            <xs:attribute name="roleID" type="xs:string"/>
                            <xs:attribute name="roleName" type="xs:string"/>
                        </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="CorporationTitlesType">
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:extension base="RowSetType">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="row" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                        <xs:complexType>
                            <xs:attribute name="titleID" type="xs:string"/>
                            <xs:attribute name="titleName" type="xs:string"/>
                        </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>

</xs:schema>
```

If you are designing this XSD there are many things you can improve. Using common names like `id` and `name` which can be differentiated by context, instead of `roleID` and `roleName`, will allow you to reuse types more. You can also use a standard notation for date/time, such as

```
<currentTime>2014-04-21T06:07:26</currentTime>
```

instead of

```
<currentTime>2014-04-21 06:07:26</currentTime>
```

Then you can use `xs:date` as the type for that element as well.

Comment: As stated in the first part of the question I'm working with an outside API and have no control over the source XML and though I might like to make the additional changes you suggested I'd have to do so across multiple API endpoints and would break many end user applications doing so since the names are also used as the DB table column names in my library ;-) Thanks for the XSD for the converted XML but I have a more detailed one using closer type checking etc but I didn't include it in my question to insure the question was easier to understand.

Comment: Well since you are considering different solutions including pre-processing, you might consider XSD 1.1 where you can use `xs:assert` to validate tags based on their content. If you can't use XSD 1.1, perhaps an XSD 1.0 extension such as Schematron, where you can also use asserts. It's easy to use them you know XSLT and XPath.

Comment: I have some limitations since I'm working in PHP and can only use default XML extensions. From what I've been able to tell at least PHP 5.3 does NOT understand anything but XSD 1.0 and to use Schematron I'd have to switch from XMLReader to DOM but I need to use streams with some of the larger APIs since they can run to several MB per and I have users with 100s even 1000s of clients data they are processing from the APIs. Using streams with some temp file system buffering works better in this application and I don't know Schematron and don't use anything that NOT a 'Standard' like XSD or XSL.